# SQL Server - Dúvida update e relação entre tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server, servidor

Tenho duas tabelas, uma chamada `coletor`, e  outra chamada `material`, tenho uma `proc` chamada `cadMat`, que era para cadastrar material no banco e pelo cpf (parametro da proc) colocar como nome do coletor os materiais que ele trouxe quando o cpf existir no banco (com uma instrução update), porém ao fazer isso a instrução altera todas linhas, e não algumas como o esperado, alguém pode me ajudar?

O código está aqui, caso ajude.

```
create proc cadMat /*Cadastra o material no banco de dados Ok!(sistema)*/
@cpfColetor char(12),
@nomeMaterial varchar(30),
@tipoMaterial varchar(8),
@zonaMaterial varchar(10),
@qtdeMaterial float,
@dataRecebimentoMaterial datetime
as
begin
    insert into material values(@nomeMaterial,@tipoMaterial,@zonaMaterial,@qtdeMaterial,@dataRecebimentoMaterial,@cpfColetor,'')
    update coletor 
    set qtdeMatCol +=@qtdeMaterial where cpfCol = @cpfColetor
    update material set nomeColMat = nomeCol from coletor where cpfCol = @cpfColetor
end
```

Comment: Oi cara, td bem?, voce pode me passar algum artigo ou link que explique bem esse conceito de join e tal?.

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço nenhum artigo a respeito disso, mas sei que existem muitos. Uma busca por "entendendo join sql" me mostrou estes artigos que acho que podem ajudar: http://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006 e https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/trabalhando-com-join/.

Answer (score 2):

O esperado, na verdade, é sim que todas as linhas de *material* sejam atualizadas. Veja o seu último comando:

```
update material set nomeColMat = nomeCol from coletor where cpfCol = @cpfColetor
```

O comando acima faz um UPDATE sem nenhum WHERE na tabela *material*; o WHERE está sendo aplicado apenas na tabela origem dos dados, a *coletor*.

Você pode buscar os dados da tabela *coletor* ligando-a através de JOIN ao seu UPDATE e informar no WHERE quais registros de *material* devem ser atualizados. Assim:

```
update material 
set material.nomeColMat = coletor.nomeCol 
from material
join coletor on coletor.cpfCol = material.cpfCol
where material.cpfCol = @cpfColetor
```

Podemos dizer que o que usamos acima foi um "*update from* com *join*".

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando "à resposta correta" do Caffé, o seu UPDATE na verdade está realizando um "CROSS JOIN" com a tabela "material" porque não está definindo os registros que devem ser afetados na sua atualização.

Para maiores informações veja:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177523.aspx