# Update com select em tabela temporaria

Tags: sql-server

Galera,
Preciso criar uma tabela temporária com 2 campos (codProduto e codBarra), e com esses registros da tabela temporária , preciso efetuar update na minha tabela principal.

Como faço update com select na tabela temporária?

Comment: Exemplo de `update from`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65182/14584. A diferença entre uma tabela temporária e uma tabela regular é apenas o prefixo `#` (temporária local) ou `##` (temporária global) no nome tabela. Exemplo: `#tabela_temporaria_local`. Tente construir seus comandos e edite sua pergunta com os problemas específicos encontrados.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem segredo:

```
update tabelaprincipal
set codBarra = temp.codBarra
from #tabelatemporaria temp
where tabelaprincipal.codProduto = temp.codProduto
```

Answer (score 0):

Raimundo,

Para efetuar uma instrução "UPDATE" com uma tabela temporária, você vai precisar vincular as informações entre a tabela que deverá ser atualizada (acredito que no seu caso o ideal seja utilizar o "codProduto").

Segue abaixo um script T-SQL para você adaptar à sua necessidade:

```
UPDATE TB_PRODUTO SET 
    codBarra = TMP.codBarra
FROM #TB_AUXILIAR AS TMP
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTO AS UPD
ON UPD.codProduto = TMP.codProduto;
GO
```

Para maiores informações veja:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177523.aspx